# Hide upper CollectionView cells with animation (Swift 4)

Tags: swift, animation, scroll, uicollectionview, swift4

How can I make it so that when I scroll down the top cells are not trimmed like mine and **hiding with animation**?

**My App:**

[image: gif]

**Example:**
[image: gif]

I tried **VegaScroll**, but it does not match the description

Comment: Off-topic: Which app is that?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri For storage of discount cards

Comment: App name i mean.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri Has not yet come up, but so far CardHolder

Comment: probably because you have 2 cells per row ?

Comment: @Tobi I know this, but are there any other options?

Comment: i can't tell honestly i've never use such a thing.

Comment: @B2Fq have you tried some work around ? + can you make it work if you had 1 cell in row ?

Comment: @B2Fq check my answer,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit you layout using the Delegate, after Setting the Layout as Vega

i've achieved this using this Code.

```
    //in viewDidLoad  
    let layout1 = VegaScrollFlowLayout()

    collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout1
```

And then using CollectionView layout Delegate

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let width = collectionView.frame.width / 3 - 1
    return CGSize(width: width, height: width)
   }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 1.0
   }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 1.0
   }
```

i don't see any code provided by you but i assume you override the Layout like this.

```
collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 20
layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: 87)
layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0)
```

And that what causes the problem, Note the above code of the solution displays 3 cells per row.

Or you can simply achieve that by using this code in ViewDidLoad.

```
    let layout1 = VegaScrollFlowLayout()

       collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout1
        layout1.minimumLineSpacing = 1
        let width =  Col1.frame.width / 3 - 1
        layout1.itemSize = CGSize(width: width , height: 87)
        layout1.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0)
```

[image: End Result]

Comment: keep in mind you need to give your correct Item Size for this to work